# Is it possible to mock a PECL extension in PHP?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

I am developing a wrapper for [datastax cassandra extension](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/).

Simple usage of the extension is like below which tries to connect to a Cassandra server on `127.0.0.1:9042`:

```php
$connection = \Cassandra::cluster()->build()->connect(); // instance of \Cassandra\DefaultSession
```

Obviously it gets errors since no running server is available.

I tried to mock all these calls step by step, but it does not work.
With package `mockery/mockery` the main problems are:

- `\Cassandra`, `\Cassandra\Cluster\Builder` and `\Cassandra\DefaultSession` are all defined as final classes
- All classes are preloaded, so proxy and partial mocking don't work
- I don't want to run a cassandra server on my machine because it cannot handle such a heavy server and also I want to setup a CI for the package I am developing

Any idea of how to handle such situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do to avoid mocking the whole universe for your test.

In this specific case creating a `CassandraSessionFactory` could already be sufficient for you to inject/mock things more easily.

I'd recommend, though, segregating into an Interface the repository responsibilities and make a Cassandra-specific implementation.

For example, let's say you have a `Person` collection/table. And you want your program to be able to fetch them. You'd then create a `PersonRepository` interface with `fetchBySomething(): Person` methods. Later on you'd be able to create a concrete implementation called `CassandraPersonRepository` which implements this using the proper extension.

With this above you can **unit test** everything that needs `PersonRepository` by mocking its interface only. And make **contract tests** for the `CassandraPersonRepository` connection only.

Check this post out: https://thephp.website/en/issue/clean-tests-with-php-and-phpunit/
There are two sections that will be helpful for your case: "Tests should have no I/O operations" and "Always inject dependencies". They show a quick way to achieve what I just mentioned.

**Bonus tip**: use Prophecy instead of phpunit's Mock. Is much easier and even faster.

I hope this answer was useful :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should develop an adapter around the cassandra API and then mock / replace that in tests.

Comment: This way I need to disable the extension for testing every time, right?